# Ubuntu freezes while watching mp4 file

Tags: video, 17.10, vlc, freeze, gedit

I have a low-end laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 100s). Sometimes, when I watch a recording of my university lectures, the whole system freezes. I can't move my mouse or use my keyboard. The freeze lasts 20 seconds or more until the system closes all programs itself and logs me out.
The videos are approx. 90 minutes long and 300 MB in size. I have only one other program (gedit) open. 
Sometime I can watch two or three lectures without problems, but other days the laptop freezes more than every ten minutes.
I use VLC media player, but the problem also happens with the default video player (Ubuntu 17.10).
There's also an automatically generated log file named "core", which appeared in my user directory. It's >70 MB in size and I can't open it with gedit. I would upload it, but my upload speed is way too low (rural Germany).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What hardware are you using, especially the video card?

Comment: I don't have a complete solution for your problem but I can suggest you to use mpv player. This is a amazing player and very light weight. To install mpv run this command without the quotes: "sudo apt install mpv".

Comment: I have an Intel Celeron N3060 processor with integrated graphics. Playing videos works fine under Windows 10 (dual boot), even in 4k. Under Ubuntu, 720p Youtube videos lag.

Comment: check when exactly this happens. if it happens when you scroll over the time slider then its a documented bug in vlc

Comment: Looks like it runs out of RAM. You need to investigate RAM usage, and also check the syslog: `free -m` and `less /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `free -h` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'`? `/var/log/syslog` may also hold useful information if you look for the entries that occurred just before the freeze. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `core` file is an indicator that the player has been terminated due to some exception, e. g. a segfault or out of memory. Given the other symptoms you describe I would bet on an out of memory situation.

Personally I experienced *VLC* being a resource hog on older machines (probably on better equipped ones, too, but you won't notice), and switched to an *mplayer* based solution. So my suggestion is you try *mpv* (as already mentioned) or *smplayer*.